# Is there some property that can be set to display the border with js api? Swiper Widget

Tags: css

How to make the distance between container and wrapper be showwing?

[image: The question is as showwing in the picture.How to make the “preButton” and “nextButton” is suspended on the distance ,not wrapper,not “swiper-slide” element]

The wrapper is filled with container actually.The border is not displayed, the “preButton” and “nextButton” is suspended on wrapper.How to make the distance between container and wrapper be showwing?  So,making the “preButton” and “nextButton” is suspended on the distance ,not wrapper.

Is there some  property that can be set to display the border with js api?

![I try to set the“margin-right: 24px” property , but it doesn’t work. Setting “magin-left:24px;” is ok.
Setting the “padding-right property” of its parent element doesn’t work also.
How to set up “swiper-wrapper” div， can make it not filled it's parent element.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fRsm.png)

The HTML Code:

```
<div class="nav-swipper swiper-container  swiper-container-horizontal">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span class="now"><b>你猜</b>测试</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span><b>你猜</b>测试</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span><b>你猜</b>测试</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span><b>你猜</b>测试</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span><b>你猜</b>测试</span></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><span><b>再猜</b>测试</span></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <!-- <div class="swiper-pagination"></div> -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.nav-swipper{background: #F2F2F2;height: 78px;box-sizing: border-box; border-top: 1px solid #979797;}
.nav-swipper .swiper-wrapper{margin: 0px 24px;}
.nav-swipper .swiper-slide {margin: 0px;text-align: center; font-size: 13px;color: #999; background: #F2F2F2; display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; -webkit-box-pack: center; -ms-flex-pack: center; -webkit-justify-content: center; justify-content: center; -webkit-box-align: center; -ms-flex-align: center; -webkit-align-items: center; align-items: center; }
.nav-swipper .swiper-button-prev{background-image:url(../images/swiper-pre.png);background-size: 12px auto;left: 2px;right: auto;width: 12px;height: 19px;}
.nav-swipper .swiper-button-next{background-image:url(../images/swiper-next.png);background-size: 12px auto;left: auto;right: 2px;width: 12px;height: 19px;}
.nav-swipper span { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;height: 64px; }
.nav-swipper b { height: 42px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 42px; text-align: center; background: #F7F7F7; border-radius: 50%; border: #fff 1px solid; color: #ccc; box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #999; }
.nav-swipper span.now b{border-color: #FF6602;}
```

JS Code:
//swipper

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.nav-swipper', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        slidesPerView: 4,
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 0,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    });
```

Comment: It's probably there but outside the viewport but this is why you are supposed to supply more markup and more than just an image.

Comment: Thank you very much. The question is updated. The code is added.  Please help me debug. Thank you. ".nav-swipper .swiper-wrapper{margin: 0px 24px;}"  The margin-right doesn't working.